# Why FastText test of a model return only 1 exemple when my test file contains 135

Tags: fasttext

I'm trying to test the model (model.bin) i've made with fastText on a test file (test.txt). In this test file, i have 135 labelised data. I'm expecting from fastText to test my model on this number of example, but instead, it only test it over 1 example. Where does come from this problem ?

I've already tried to do such a thing with another model and another testing file and all worked nicely.

this is how I test my model. model_baby.bin is the model, and test.data.txt is my testing file.

```
./fasttext test model_baby.bin test.data.txt 

N       1

P@1     1

R@1     0.0164

Number of examples: 1
```

And here is an extract from my testing file

> __label__4.0 I love the fact you can hide your stuff. Only down is that the straps to hold it at midpoint and bottom could be better designed for your car.  It's got plenty of room which is great. __label__5.0 This hid our ipad wonderfully. Especially for those quick stops where we all had jump out and use the restroom. It zipped, folded and held all our stuff for the kids in the back seat. __label__3.0

As i have more than 1 labelised example in my testing file, I expect the output "Number of examples: " to be at least more than 1 but the actual one is "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official documentation (https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html): Each line of the text file contains a list of labels, followed by the corresponding document. All the labels start by the __label__ prefix, which is how fastText recognize what is a label or what is a word.

I don't understand very much your extract. I think it should be like this:

```
__label__4.0 I love the fact you can hide your stuff. Only down is that the straps to hold it at midpoint and bottom could be better designed for your car. It's got plenty of room which is great. 
__label__5.0 This hid our ipad wonderfully. Especially for those quick stops where we all had jump out and use the restroom. It zipped, folded and held all our stuff for the kids in the back seat. 
__label__3.0 ...
```

Comment: I put my test file as you recomanded and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much